# How to pass wrapper class value as parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I have a VF page with controller and in this controller it contain a Wrapper class which is displaying the value apex:pageBlocktable. I have a print button which call a another Vf page where i need to display some values from Wrapper class. I try to use the same controller from both 2 VF pages but it don't work because i call the class and refresh all the values in the class. So i wrote another controller for print VF page but i am not able to pass the values from Wrapper class. Is their any method to do it. Or if their is any other idea, i am open to new idea.

Comment: could you please post code so that its clear what you are upto

Comment: Agree with Mohith, you need to post your code.  At first glance though you should be able to use the same controller for this.  If you are just returning a pagereference in your controller to switch to the new page without setting redirect(true), it should not reinitialize and therefore reset your controller properties.  If you post your code though, it would be much more clear as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is pass one variable from one controller to another, if so, then you would do that using a PageReference like this:

```
//This method puts current controller variables in a VF page
public PageReference paginaNuevas(){
    //these are variables obtained from jquery
    String fechaInicio = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('event_start_date_alternate');
    String fechaFin = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('event_stop_date_alternate');

    PageReference pr = Page.ChurnRate_Nuevas;
            //Empresa is a local variable
    pr.getParameters().put('empresa', empresa);
    pr.getParameters().put('fechaInicio', fechaInicio);
    pr.getParameters().put('fechaFin', fechaFin);
    pr.getParameters().put('paquetes', paquete);
    pr.getParameters().put('paquetesDetalles',paqueteDetalle);
    return pr;
}

//this method calls the variables from your VF page

public limitWrapper[] getthousandBlocks()
{
    thousandBlocks = new limitWrapper[]{};

    empresa = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('empresa');
    String fechaInicio = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fechaInicio');
    paquete = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('paquetes');
    paqueteDetalle = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('paquetesDetalles');
 }
```

Hope this make sense to you

Regards!